# Spring Security Login page and register user on the same html file

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am a bit new to spring and am currently trying to create a web application that involves logging in a user with spring boot security. The initial login authentication worked when I had the login page and create a user page as two separate HTML files. Now I am trying to create a single webpage using javascript. However, I am not able to access the pages anymore.

This is my user Entity

```
package com.fncd.model;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;

import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(name="fncd_users", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long user_id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(String first_name, String last_name, String email, String password) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Users(String first_name, String last_name, String email, String password,
            Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Users {" + 
               "user_id=" + user_id + 
               ", first_name=" + first_name + 
               ", last_name=" + last_name + 
               ", email=" + email + 
               ", password=" + password + 
               ", roles=" + roles + "}";
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Long getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(Long user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }


    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

This is my security configuration

```
package com.fncd.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.fncd.service.UserServiceSec;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceSec userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login**", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/imgs/**", "/webjars/**", "/views/**")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard", true).permitAll().and().logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

}
```

My App controller

```
package com.fncd.controller;

import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils;

@Controller
public class AppController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model m) {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String userIndex() {
        return "user/dashboard";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/dashboard")
    public String dashboard() {
        return "dashboard";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/dashboard_2")
    public String dashboard_2() {
        return "dashboard_2";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/header")
    public String header() {
        return "header";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/footer")
    public String footer() {
        return "footer";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/annual_report")
    public String report_overview() {
        return "annual_report";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/settings")
    public String settings() {
        return "settings";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/change_pw")
    public String change_pw() {
        return "change_pw";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/forgot_pw")
    public String forgot_pw() {
        return "forgot_pw";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/forgot_pw_1")
    public String forgot_pw_1() {
        return "forgot_pw_1";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/forgot_pw_2")
    public String forgot_pw_2() {
        return "forgot_pw_2";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/success")
    public String getSuccess(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, ?> inputFlashMap = RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request);
        if (inputFlashMap != null) {
            return "success";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/dashboard"; // if user refresh success page
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping("/fail")
    public String getError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, ?> inputFlashMap = RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request);
        if (inputFlashMap != null) {
            return "fail";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/dashboard"; // if user refresh success page
        }
    }
}
```

User registration controller

```
package com.fncd.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.fncd.model.Users;
import com.fncd.registrationdto.UserRegistrationDto;
import com.fncd.service.UserServiceSec;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/create_user")
public class UserRegistrationController {

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceSec userServiceSec;

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public UserRegistrationDto userRegistrationDto() {
        return new UserRegistrationDto();
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String showCreateUserPage(Model m) {
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String createUserAccount(@ModelAttribute("user")@Valid UserRegistrationDto userRegistrationDto, 
            BindingResult result) {
        Users existing = userServiceSec.findByEmail(userRegistrationDto.getEmail());
        if(existing != null) 
            result.rejectValue("email", null, "There is already an account registered with that email");
        if(result.hasErrors())
            return "create_user";

            userServiceSec.save(userRegistrationDto);

            return "redirect:/?success";        
    }
}
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-show-password.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-show-password/1.0.3/bootstrap-show-password.min.js"></script>
<title>Finance Calculator Daily</title>
</head>
<style>
/* ------------------------------------ Click on login and Sign Up to  changue and view the effect
---------------------------------------
*/
* {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.cotn_principal {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#cfd8dc+0,607d8b+100,b0bec5+100 */
    background: #092756;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104, 128, 138, .4)
        10%, rgba(138, 114, 76, 0) 40%),
        -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(57, 173, 219, .25) 0%,
        rgba(42, 60, 87, .4) 100%),
        -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #670d10 0%, #092756 100%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104, 128, 138, .4)
        10%, rgba(138, 114, 76, 0) 40%),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(57, 173, 219, .25) 0%,
        rgba(42, 60, 87, .4) 100%),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #670d10 0%, #092756 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104, 128, 138, .4)
        10%, rgba(138, 114, 76, 0) 40%),
        -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(57, 173, 219, .25) 0%,
        rgba(42, 60, 87, .4) 100%),
        -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #670d10 0%, #092756 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104, 128, 138, .4)
        10%, rgba(138, 114, 76, 0) 40%),
        -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(57, 173, 219, .25) 0%,
        rgba(42, 60, 87, .4) 100%),
        -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #670d10 0%, #092756 100%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104, 128, 138, .4)
        10%, rgba(138, 114, 76, 0) 40%),
        linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(57, 173, 219, .25) 0%,
        rgba(42, 60, 87, .4) 100%),
        linear-gradient(135deg, #670d10 0%, #092756 100%);
}

.cont_centrar {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.cont_login {
    position: relative;
    width: 640px;
    left: 40%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.cont_back_info {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 640px;
    height: 280px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 100px;
    box-shadow: 1px 10px 30px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.cont_forms {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 280px;
    background-color: #eee;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.cont_forms_active_login {
    box-shadow: 1px 10px 30px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 420px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.cont_forms_active_sign_up {
    box-shadow: 1px 10px 30px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 420px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 320px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.cont_img_back_grey {
    position: absolute;
    width: 950px;
    top: -80px;
    left: -116px;
}

.cont_img_back_grey>img {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    opacity: 0.2;
    animation-name: animar_fondo;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

.cont_img_back_ {
    position: absolute;
    width: 950px;
    top: -80px;
    left: -116px;
}

.cont_img_back_>img {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.3;
    animation-name: animar_fondo;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

.cont_forms_active_login>.cont_img_back_ {
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.cont_forms_active_sign_up>.cont_img_back_ {
    top: 0px;
    left: -435px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.cont_info_log_sign_up {
    position: absolute;
    width: 640px;
    height: 280px;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.col_md_login {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.col_md_login>h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 70px;
    color: #757575;
}

.col_md_login>p {
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 80%;
    color: #37474F;
}

.btn_login {
    background-color: #26C6DA;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.col_md_sign_up {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.cont_ba_opcitiy>h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
}

.cont_ba_opcitiy>p {
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 15px;
    color: #fff;
}
/* ----------------------------------
background text    
------------------------------------
 */
.cont_ba_opcitiy {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(120, 144, 156, 0.55);
    width: 80%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding: 15px 0px;
}

.btn_sign_up {
    background-color: #ef5350;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cont_forms_active_sign_up {
    z-index: 2;
}

@
-webkit-keyframes animar_fondo {from { -webkit-transform:scale(1)translate(0px);
    -moz-transform: scale(1) translate(0px);
    -ms-transform: scale(1) translate(0px);
    -o-transform: scale(1) translate(0px);
    transform: scale(1) translate(0px);
}

to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5) translate(50px);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5) translate(50px);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5) translate(50px);
    -o-transform: scale(1.5) translate(50px);
    transform: scale(1.5) translate(50px);
}

}
@
-o-keyframes identifier {from { -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    -o-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

}
@
-moz-keyframes identifier {from { -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    -o-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

}
@
keyframes identifier {from { -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    -o-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

}
.cont_form_login {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    width: 320px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.cont_forms_active_login {
    z-index: 2;
}

.cont_forms_active_login>.cont_form_login {

}

.cont_form_sign_up {
    position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    float: left;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.cont_form_sign_up>input {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 260px;
    border: none;
    color: #757575;
}

.cont_form_sign_up>h2 {
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #757575;
}

.cont_form_login>input {
    padding: 15px 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 260px;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    color: #757575;
}

.cont_form_login>h2 {
    margin-top: 110px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #757575;
}

.cont_form_login>a, .cont_form_sign_up>a {
    color: #757575;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.item img {
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: cover;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 500px;
}
/* .invalid class prevents CSS from automatically applying */
.invalid input:required:invalid {
    background: #BE4C54;
}

/* Mark valid inputs during .invalid state */
.invalid input:required:valid {
    background: #17D654;
}
</style>
<script>
    /* ------------------------------------ Click on login and Sign Up to  changue and view the effect
     ---------------------------------------
     */

    function cambiar_login() {
        document.querySelector('.cont_forms').className = "cont_forms cont_forms_active_login";
        document.querySelector('.cont_form_login').style.display = "block";
        document.querySelector('.cont_form_sign_up').style.opacity = "0";

        setTimeout(function() {
            document.querySelector('.cont_form_login').style.opacity = "1";
        }, 400);

        setTimeout(
                function() {
                    document.querySelector('.cont_form_sign_up').style.display = "none";
                }, 200);
    }

    function cambiar_sign_up(at) {
        document.querySelector('.cont_forms').className = "cont_forms cont_forms_active_sign_up";
        document.querySelector('.cont_form_sign_up').style.display = "block";
        document.querySelector('.cont_form_login').style.opacity = "0";

        setTimeout(function() {
            document.querySelector('.cont_form_sign_up').style.opacity = "1";
        }, 100);

        setTimeout(function() {
            document.querySelector('.cont_form_login').style.display = "none";
        }, 400);

    }

    function ocultar_login_sign_up() {

        document.querySelector('.cont_forms').className = "cont_forms";
        document.querySelector('.cont_form_sign_up').style.opacity = "0";
        document.querySelector('.cont_form_login').style.opacity = "0";

        setTimeout(
                function() {
                    document.querySelector('.cont_form_sign_up').style.display = "none";
                    document.querySelector('.cont_form_login').style.display = "none";
                }, 500);

    }

    (function() {
        'use strict';
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
            var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
            // Loop over them and prevent submission
            var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
                form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }
                    form.classList.add('was-validated');
                }, false);
            });
        }, false);
    })();
</script>

<body>

    <div class="cotn_principal">
        <h1
            style="text-align: left; font-family: fantasy; margin-left: 200px; margin-top: 70px; margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 72px; color: antiquewhite; width: 30%;">Welcome</h1>
        <div class="cont_centrar ">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="cont_login">
                    <div class="cont_info_log_sign_up">
                        <div class="col_md_login">
                            <div class="cont_ba_opcitiy">

                                <h2>LOGIN</h2>
                                <p>Welcome back to FNCD Budget Planner!</p>
                                <button class="btn_login" onclick="cambiar_login()">LOGIN</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col_md_sign_up">
                            <div class="cont_ba_opcitiy">
                                <h2>SIGN UP</h2>


                                <p>Get started with FNCD Budget Planner!</p>

                                <button class="btn_sign_up" onclick="cambiar_sign_up()">SIGN
                                    UP</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="cont_back_info">
                        <div class="cont_img_back_grey">
                            <img
                                src="https://images.unsplash.com/42/U7Fc1sy5SCUDIu4tlJY3_NY_by_PhilippHenzler_philmotion.de.jpg?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=50&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=7686972873678f32efaf2cd79671673d"
                                alt="" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="cont_forms">
                        <div class="cont_img_back_">
                            <img
                                src="https://images.unsplash.com/42/U7Fc1sy5SCUDIu4tlJY3_NY_by_PhilippHenzler_philmotion.de.jpg?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=50&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=7686972873678f32efaf2cd79671673d"
                                alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="cont_form_login">
                            <a href="#" onclick="ocultar_login_sign_up()"><i
                                class="material-icons">&#xE5C4;</i></a>
                            <h2>LOGIN</h2>
                            <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post"
                                class="needs-validation" novalidate>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"
                                        id="username" name="username" required />
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter the correct
                                        email!</div>
                                    <br> <input type="password" class="form-control"
                                        id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"
                                        data-toggle="password" required />
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Password is incorrect</div>
                                    <div class="row clearfix">
                                        <a class=" btn btn-link " href="forgot_pw.html" role="button">Forgot
                                            Password</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="dashboard.html">
                                        <button type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit"
                                            class="btn_login" onclick="cambiar_login()">LOGIN</button>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    <form action="#" th:action="@{/create_user}" th:object="${user}"
                            method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate id="cform"
                            oninput='rcpwd.setCustomValidity(rcpwd.value != cpwd.value ? "Passwords do not match." :"")'>
                            <div class="cont_form_sign_up">
                                <a href="#" onclick="ocultar_login_sign_up()"><i
                                    class="material-icons">&#xE5C4;</i></a>
                                <h2>SIGN UP</h2>

                                <input type="text" th:field="*{first_name}" class="form-control"
                                    id="cfn" placeholder="First Name" name="createfirstname"
                                    style="margin-top: 0; height: 3.6rem;" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,10}"
                                    required />
                                <div class="invalid-feedback ">Only alphabets are allowed</div>
                                <input type="text" th:field="*{last_name}" class="form-control"
                                    id="cln" placeholder="Last Name" name="createlastname"
                                    style="margin-top: 14px; height: 3.6rem;"
                                    pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,10}" required />
                                <div class="invalid-feedback ">Only alphabets are allowed</div>
                                <input type="email" th:field="*{email}" class="form-control"
                                    id="cemail" name="email" placeholder="Email"
                                    style="margin-top: 14px; height: 3.6rem;"
                                    pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" required />
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">Wrong email format</div>
                                <input type="password" th:field="*{password}"
                                    class="form-control" id="cpwd" placeholder="Password"
                                    name="createpassword" style="margin-top: 14px; height: 3.6rem;"
                                    pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" required />
                                <div class="invalid-feedback inline-block text-break">
                                    Passwords are case sensitive and must contain at least 8
                                    characters, 1 upper case letter, 1 lower case letter and 1
                                    number.</div>
                                <input type="password" th:field="*{confirmPassword}"
                                    class="form-control" id="confirmPassword"
                                    placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirmPassword"
                                    style="margin-top: 14px; height: 3.6rem; margin-bottom: 15px;"
                                    required />
                                <div class="invalid-feedback ">Password do not match</div>
                                <a href="login.html">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn_sign_up">SIGN UP</button>
                                </a>

                            </div>
                        </form> 
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide"
                data-ride="carousel">
                <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0"
                        class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="carousel-item active" style="height: 500px;">
                        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="imgs/BP%20quote.jpg"
                            alt="First slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <!-- <div class="banner-text">-->
                            <h1
                                style="font-size: 55px; padding-bottom: 280px; font-family: serif">FNCD
                                Budget Planner!</h1>
                            <p style="color: black; font-size: 10p;">Struggling to keep
                                track of your expenses? FNCD is here to help!</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="imgs/budgeting.png.jpg"
                            alt="First slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <div class="banner-text">
                                <h2>This is Heaven</h2>
                                <p>Beware of little expenses; a small leak will sink a great
                                    ship!</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="imgs/manage-your-finances.jpg"
                            alt="First slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <div class="banner-text">
                                <h2>Save money to buy future</h2>
                                <p>Sign up FNCD Budget planner to manage your money better!</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the error I am getting:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
>       at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
>       at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
>       at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
>       at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
>       at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
>       ... 88 common frames omitted

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!